# How can i sum the count of rows of two different tables (duplicate include) in sql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

The First table is Assigned_receipt & sql query is below,having 24 rows(for ex):

```
<?php
              $sql = "SELECT * FROM `task_list` where task_id in (SELECT task_id FROM `task_assignees` where employee_id = '{$_SESSION['employee_id']}') order by strftime('%s',date_created) desc";
  $qry = $conn->query($sql);
                $i = 1;
                    while($row = $qry->fetchArray()):
                ?>
```

The Second table is created_receipt & sql query is below, having 8 rows(for ex):

```
<?php  
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `task_list` where department_id = '{$_SESSION['department_id']}' order by strftime('%s',date_created) desc";
                $qry = $conn->query($sql);
                $i = 1;
                    while($row = $qry->fetchArray()):
                ?>
```

Table task_list have below columns:

```
CREATE TABLE "task_list" (
    "task_id"   INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "task_code" TEXT NOT NULL,
    "title" TEXT NOT NULL,
    "description"   TEXT NOT NULL,
    "department_id" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "employee_id"   INTEGER,
    "status"    INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    "date_created"  TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    "date_updated"  TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    "date"  TEXT,
    FOREIGN KEY("employee_id") REFERENCES "employee_list"("employee_id") on DELETE SET NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY("department_id") REFERENCES "department_list"("department_id") on DELETE CASCADE,
    PRIMARY KEY("task_id" AUTOINCREMENT)
);
```

Table task_assignees having below column:

```
CREATE TABLE "task_assignees" (
    "task_id"   INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "employee_id"   INTEGER NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY("task_id") REFERENCES "task_list"("task_id") on DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY("employee_id") REFERENCES "employee_list"("employee_id") on DELETE CASCADE
);
```

How can i get the sum of rows (combinedly 24+8=32) as a single result?
I am using below query: but it is throwing error:

```
<?php
$task=$conn->query("SELECT sum(count) as `total_count` from(SELECT count(task_id) as `count` FROM `task_list` where task_id in(SELECT task_id FROM `task_assignees` where employee_id = '{$_SESSION['employee_id']}')) UNION ALL (SELECT count(task_id) as `count` FROM `task_list` where department_id = '{$_SESSION['department_id']}')")->fetchArray()['total_count'];
  echo $task > 0 ? number_format($total_count) : 0 ;
                          ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

trying to understand,
From your model "task_list" already have the employee_id, I'm assuming it's like responsible, where task_assignees is who will actually do the task or multiple employees.

If that's the case always try to be as simple and verbose as possible. Meaning rename field to what bus logic infers, so anyone in the future will understand quickly what it means.

Try the following:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) AS `count`
FROM `task_list`
    INNER JOIN `task_assignees` ON `task_assignees`.`task_id` = `task_list`.`task_id`
WHERE `task_list`.`department_id` = '{$_SESSION[' department_id ']}'
    AND `task_assignees`.`employee_id` = '{$_SESSION[' employee_id ']}'
```

it will output the number of rows which would be equal to the number of tasks.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but the query still not working. It is showing 0 as output. 
<?php                                                                                 $task=$conn->query("SELECT COUNT(1) AS `count`
FROM `task_list`
    INNER JOIN `task_assignees` ON `task_assignees`.`task_id` = `task_list`.`task_id`
WHERE `task_list`.`department_id` = '{$_SESSION[' department_id ']}'
    AND `task_assignees`.`employee_id` = '{$_SESSION[' employee_id ']}'")->fetchArray()['count'];
                          echo $task > 0 ? number_format($task) : 0 ;
                          ?>